# How to implement WebSocketSharp Unity Client with SSL/TLS connection that has to be connected to Node.js Server?

Tags: node.js, ssl, tls1.2, x509certificate2, websocket-sharp

Following is my simple Node.js server.

```
const { createServer } = require('https');
const { WebSocketServer, createWebSocketStream } = require('ws');
const { readFileSync } = require('fs');
const server = createServer({
    cert: readFileSync('certs/x509.crt'),
    key: readFileSync('certs/x509.key')
});

const wss = new WebSocketServer({ server });

wss.on('connection', (ws) => {
    console.log('One client has connected.');
    ws.on('message', (data) => {
        console.log('data received: %s', data);
        ws.send(data.toString());
    })
    ws.on('close', () => {
        console.log('One client has disconnected.');
    })
})

server.listen(8080, '127.0.0.1', () => {
    console.log(`Server HTTPS WS launched 127.0.0.1:${ 8080}`)
});
```

my node.js folder includes the certs folder.
In Godot Engine, it succeeded when using WebSocketPeer, X509Certificate, and StreamPeerBuffer.
But when it comes to Unity...
Following is my simple Unity's NetworkClient.cs file content.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using WebSocketSharp;
using WebSocketSharp.Net;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Runtime.ConstrainedExecution;
using System;

public class NetworkClient : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    WebSocket ws;
    void Start()
    {
        var cert = new X509Certificate2("Assets/Certs/x509.crt");
        var sslConfig = new ClientSslConfiguration("localhost");
        var ws = new WebSocket("wss://localhost:8080");
        ws.OnMessage += (sender, e) => 
        {
            Debug.Log("Message received from " + ((WebSocket)sender).Url + " Data : " + e.Data);
        };
        ws.Connect();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (ws == null)
        {
            return;    
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            ws.Send("Hello");
        }
    }
}
```

I know that this wasn't even an implementation of TLS, but then how should I establish an SSL/TLS connection? I am new to network programming, especially with Unity, and I couldn't find a related FAQ on the Internet.

I expected a "Hello" sent to the server and echo a "Hello" when the space key is pressed. The connection is established over SSL/TLS.

Comment: The problem solved, thanks you so much.

Comment: Can you show us how you solved the problem? It would be very helpful